# How to convert to date format when varchar2(7) value are being passed when there is variation?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I'm being passed data in varchar2(7) format that i need to convert into date format and then in insert in my trigger. I know that the function to_Date(date, 'dddyyyy') exists but there are  values that are in both dddyyyy and ddyyyy format. I've tried the following but still getting a 'day of month must be between 1 and last day of month' error. My code is below:

```
Insert into Submission
(RESPONDENT_ID, SUBMISSION_DT, SUBMISSION_TYPE_ID, SUBMISSION_NAME_TX, SUBMISSION_SEQ_NB, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID, MODIFY_DT, MODIFY_USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, INACTIVE_DT)
VALUES
('2527451', CASE WHEN :new.data_date > 99999 then To_Date(:new.data_Date, 'dddyyyy') ELSE To_Date(:new.data_Date, 'ddyyyy') END, '1', '20190418', '0', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);
```

sample data for data_date:

```
612014 3652014 012015
```

desired result:

```
Mar-02-2014 (3/1/YYYY for leap year), Dec-31-2014 (Dec-30 for leap year), Jan-01-2015.
```

So my question is, even with the LPAD method, there are 9 days in the calendar year that are not accounted for (1YYYY - 9YYYY to be exact). What do i do for these dates? the dates are in varchar format so I can't use a operational conditional statement (i.e. CASE WHEN :new.data_date <= 10000 THEN to_date(lpad(:new.data_Date, 7, '00'), 'DDDYYYY')

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `dddyyyy` is day of year followed by year. That's ok.  However, what format is `ddyyyy`?  Day of month followed by 4 digit year? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: so there is data in the database that has only 2 digits for the day of the year. (i.e. 612015)

Comment: So the first 2 or 3 values are integer representing the day of the year?

Comment: yes DDYYYY OR DDDYYYY, there may be DYYYY as well

Comment: @GordonLinoff provided sample data and desired results...

Comment: your example "612014" isn't in ddyyyy format.  My guess is that someone loaded the data into Excel first, which saw it as a number field and stripped the leading zero.  As Gordon Linoff suggests, just pad with leading zeros and just use dddyyyy format.

Comment: oh my mistake, i forgot to add the part about what we need to do if we get values only have a single digit in the day field. (DYYYY i.e. 12015). My mistake

Answer (score 2):

How about just padding the number on the left?

```
Insert into Submission (RESPONDENT_ID, SUBMISSION_DT, SUBMISSION_TYPE_ID, SUBMISSION_NAME_TX, SUBMISSION_SEQ_NB, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID, MODIFY_DT, MODIFY_USER_ID, EFFECTIVE_DT, INACTIVE_DT)
    values ('2527451',
            to_date(lpad(:new.data_Date, 7, '0'), 'DDDYYYY'),
           '1', '20190418', '0', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null
           );
```

Note:  If values in the table are numbers, then do not use single quotes for their values.

Comment: i get a too many arguments for function error...

Comment: oh i know what it may be, paranthese after the 0, haha

Comment: what happens if the data is in DYYYY format? do i just use a case statement where i add two 0s?

Comment: @icerabbit . . . The `lpad()` takes care of that as well.

Comment: so it'll know automatically when to put 1 zero or 2 zeroes correct?